# Core Bluetooth Branding

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am working with CoreBluetooth for the first time. I have been told that the `UIAlertView` that comes up for BlueTooth pairing cannot be changed/branded. Is this true? Is there no Apple Blue Tooth API that permits use of a custom interface for providing pairing information?

T[image]

Comment: That is correct. It is a system dialog.  You can't change it

Comment: @Paulw11 So I just tried out the FitBit app, and that did not use a UIAlertView to obtain the passcode used to pair the devices. How did they do it?

Comment: Fitbit doesn't use pairing. They may use some other, private, passcode protocol to decrypt the data. If you use the LightBlue app from the App Store you will see that it can just connect to a Fitbit without pairing.